# Why is my knockout.js value not being saved?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

**Update:** I added [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeWills/SPqjm/) of my problem. I also completely rewrote the question as ideas have changed.

I have a page where I am using knockout.js for the layout. I have this working successfully on another page in my application, but I can't get this one to work. My model consists of a parent record and it's child records. My problem is when I try to make copy of the previous row to make it easier for the user to add many similar records. When I type values in the my Department, Project, Job, and Comment fields, the values are blank in the model so when I go to copy those fields, they remain blank.=. Any ideas? I am guessing I am missing something stupid.

```
 function DayViewModel(day) {
     var self = this;

     self.Date = day.Date;
     self.Time = day.Time;
     self.Hours = ko.observable(day.Hours);
     self.TimesheetCode = ko.observable(day.TimesheetCode);
     self.Department = ko.observable(day.Department);
     self.Project = ko.observable(day.Project);
     self.Job = ko.observable(day.Job);
     self.Comments = ko.observable(day.Comments);
     self.JobIsRequired = ko.observable((day.JobIsRequired == undefined) ? false : day.JobIsRequired);
 }

 function RequestViewModel() {
     var self = this;

     self.DaysRequested = ko.observableArray([new DayViewModel({
         Date: new Date().toString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
         Time: "08:00 AM",
         Hours: 1,
         TimesheetCode: "",
         Department: 0,
         Project: 0,
         Job: 0,
         Comments: ""
     })]);
     self.timesheetCodes // gets data from an external data source

     // Add another day copying the previous day.
     self.addDay = function () {
         var array = self.DaysRequested();
         var previousDay = array[array.length - 1];
         previousDay.Date = Date.parse(previousDay.Date).addDays(1).toString("MM/dd/yyyy");

         var test = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(previousDay.Department);

         var newDay = new DayViewModel({
             Date: previousDay.Date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
             Time: previousDay.Time,
             Hours: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(previousDay.Hours),
             Department: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(previousDay.Department),
             Project: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(previousDay.Project),
             Job: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(previousDay.Job),
             Comments: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(previousDay.Comments),
             TimesheetCode: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(previousDay.TimesheetCode)
         });
         self.DaysRequested.push(newDay);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net, with your HTML, JS and CSS so that we can debug your issue?

Comment: So what is broken?  Can you describe what the user does, what you expect to happen, and what actually happens?  All we know is 'Knockout value not saved' and 'it doesnt work'.  Can you elaborate what what's not working?

Comment: @CodeThug Sorry, I must have been distracted and forgot to add exactly what was wrong.

Comment: @nickyt added the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the text binding on some of your fields when you need the value binding.  For example, Department should be

```
<input type="text" class="input-small department-entry" max="5" data-bind="value: Department, uniqueName: true" />
```

Comment: @Mike Willis - that fiddle still has the text binding.  You also don't need the parenthesis in the binding.  Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/SPqjm/4/

Comment: I see what I did wrong now. Like I said... something stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Other than your observable array, the only observable you have is TimesheetCode.  From the ko [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html):

> An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array, not the
>   state of those objects

I'm guessing that you've bound the Date, Time, Hours, etc. to input boxes on your page and are expecting updates that the user types into those input boxes to be reflected in the underlying javascript objects, but they aren't, thus the 'Knockout value not saved.'

If this is the case, then I would recommend creating Date, Time, Hours, etc., as observables.

If you need a more detailed solution, please provide a more detailed problem, including the relevant markup.

Comment: The date and time and working perfectly. It's the other fields that are not working. Which makes this stranger.